# Passing Self ViewController as a Parameter?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a TableView inside my app and i populate it from a JSON, which is downloaded inside a DataService class. This DataService class simply does the download & save data to array operation.

Inside my ViewController class, i also have an array for this data that is initialized empty at the beginning, filled with the data from DataService afterwards. Since i need to fill the data array (the one inside ViewController class) once the download operation is completed, DataService class needs to reach this array. So i decided to pass the ViewController object itself to DataService class so that it can fill VC's array with downloaded data and also reload its tableView data.

So my DataService class looks like this:

```
var dataArray: [EtkinlikCellData] = []

func fetchData(senderVC: EtkinliklerVC)  {

  // Download & fill dataArray operations

  senderVC.dataArray = self.dataArray // setting sender VC's array
  senderVC.tableView.reloadData() // reloading sender VC's table data

}
```

And how's it used inside ViewController class:

```
var dataArray = [EtkinlikCellData]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self 
    DataService.instance.fetchData(senderVC: self)

}
```

I know that if i did the fetch operation directly inside the ViewController class, there would be no problems since fetchData() method would reach the dataArray and tableView object itself. But since it is in another class, would it be wrong or harmful to pass a ViewController object as a  parameter? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only threat is retain cycles and you can avoid it with weakly reference the object like

**Option 1:**  // problem model shouldn't have any UI content

```
weak var delgate:EtkinliklerVC?
fetchData(senderVC: EtkinliklerVC)  {
 self.delegate = senderVC

 ....
 self.delegate?.dataArray = self.dataArray  
 self.delegate?.tableView.reloadData()
```

**Option 2 :**

Establish a completion ( Recommended )

```
func fetchData(completion:@escaping:([String] -> ()))   {  
  completion(arr)
}
```

then use it

```
DataService.instance.fetchData() { [weak self] arr in
 // set it and reload
}
```

**Plus:**

Say you left your current code as it's , since the singleton alive which means it's strongly retained and you pass the vc object to it , user opens the vc and before data returns he pressed back button in your vc , since there is no weak reference between the singleton and the vc , then the vc will still be in memory while it should be de allocated

Comment: Thank you, also could you please explain more about Option 1? What's the point of setting the VC object as a weak var after it is recieved already?

Comment: search for retain cycles ios

Comment: Doesn't the VC parameter be removed from the memory automatically once it the method is executed? Since i am not saving it to a global variable ?

Comment: no the closure establishes a strong reference to it